# Is there a way for wordpress members to log back on to where they left off?

Tags: wordpress

Hi I have a wordpress website where people can sign up to read my posts and I was wondering if there's a way they can log back on to where they left off on?

Comment: you can use post meta fields to store what users have read each posts and then show them this information some way with a list of posts and marked what they have read or in each entry show a banner "read", "not read".